# HTML Debit Card Expiry Date

Tags: html

I am doing a small website and part of my website is implementing a minor payment page. I opted to do a couple of fields, including Card Number, expiry date and cc number. The only problem is that I do not know what type of field I am going to set the Expiry date to be, since I just need it to show the month and year. Anyone can help please?

Comment: One select box for the months and one select box for the year selection

Comment: Implementing your own payment flow in your website is really dangeros and highly discouraged. It will scare off your customers. They don't want to input serious numbers into unsecured forms. I suggest using other APIs supported by named companies(e.g. Stripe).

Comment: If your current skill level is such that you have trouble making the basic input elements in the form, I would strongly recommend against making a payment page yourself.

Comment: Without java-script it will be very difficult, visit this https://codepen.io/squegg/pen/baNRdV

Comment: Also, please read the tag descriptions when using them, [tag:visa] explicitly says "DO NOT USE this tag for the payment card Visa, nor for a travel visa related question". Even if that was a payment card-related tag, this question hardly has anything to do with Visa cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible method is to use just **number** for both the fields (month and year) if you do not have any date validations going in the backend. For example,

```html
<input type = "number" placeholder = "MM" id = "month" maxlength = 2 /> /
<input type = "number" placeholder = "YY" id = "year" maxlength = 2 />
```

Run the code snippet to view the output.

That should help! Please reply with your feedback on the answer.

Regards, 
Manoj

Comment: A payment endpoint should most definitely have validation for all values. Anybody can change the type of the input in the browser developer tools or just use some other tool to send any kind of requests to your endpoint.

Comment: "minor" payment page! if the developer is intending for a connection between payment gateway, such an API would provide the necessary HTML for the input. Since this is a simple case, it is okay to go with a number field

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add the select box both for the month and year. And the required validations you can add to that select box.

Or

You can also proceed with input text where it should allow 2 digits for both the inputs. And required validations you can apply on the input type.

But i will opt for select box.